# How to send a long(160 or more characters) text message?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sms, pdu, gsmcomm

Everyone

I am trying to write a code in c# where I could send a text message that has 160 or more characters using the GSMComm libray.

What I've done is I divided my message into parts/message and send them to my clients. The problem is, the clients find it irritating.

So, is there a way to send a long text message?

*Update

I found this on their website:

> **Q**: How can I send long (concatenated) text messages?
>     **A**: GSMComm implements a part of the "Smart Messaging" standard defined by      Nokia. The methods for it are implemented in the GsmComm.PduConverter.SmartMessaging.SmartMessageFactory class. It supports creating long messages for standard SMS text as well as for Unicode messages (Built-in Unicode conversion starts with Version 1.61).

But I can't find their documentation so i don't know how to use the SmartMessaging.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21789103/249552

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.sohua.xyz/questions-full/5655476/how-to-send-sms-with-more-than-160-characters-and-enable-the-customer-to-receive):

> If using HTTP, you gotta set the MLC to 2. Message length control.
>   Determines system behavior when the message length exceeds limits set
>   by the mobile operator. 0 – Reject the MT if message text > maximum
>   allowed for the target operator. 1 – Truncate the MT if message text >
>   maximum allowed for the target operator. 2 – Automatically create
>   multiple MTs dividing the message text at the point(s) where message
>   text length = maximum allowed for the target operator.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am texting via phone connected to my desktop via USB cable.